# How to develop new Qt GUI controls?

Tags: c++, qt

There are some Qt controls like QButton, QLabel etc. 
Can I develop new Qt GUI control, for example QAccordion or QRibbon control?

How is this done, and from where can I read and learn about it?

Comment: If you're looking for those specific widgets, you should probably check out QToolBox and QtitanRibbon.

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own widgets by subclassing [QWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QWidget.html) or existing QWidget subclasses, (e.g., [QFrame](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qframe.html))

Honestly, at this stage, though, I recommend familiarizing yourself with how Qt works before trying to create entirely new widgets. There are several books about Qt, my favorite of which is [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131872494), which, among other things, shows you how to create your own widgets.

Answer (score 1):

> Can i develop new

Yes.

> how to develop new own qt gui controls?
>
> where can i read and learn it?

You should read [qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/). Documentation is quite good, so there's no excuse for not reading it.

[Analog clock](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/widgets-analogclock.html) example shows how to create custom widget.

Answer (score 0):

And here you can see how-to use it qtdesigner http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html